# OpenCV3.0: linking error WITH_CUDA=ON

Tags: c++, opencv

I downloaded opencv3.0 & opencv_contrib then used Cmake-GUI to compile the libraries. I have my flags WITH_CUDA=ON, WITH_OPENCL=ON, WITH_OPENMP=ON.
I made sure I am generating for VS 2013 64-bit. Cmake-GUI runs perfectly fine.
Issue is building OpenCV solution file in VS 2013. I keep getting errors like in the below attached photo.

[image]

My CUDA samples are running perfectly fine.
I am not sure whether if i am missing something in the process or is it a bug?

CUDA - 7.5
OpenCV3.0
VS 2013

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. They are not helpful and can't be searched. Further, you talk about a compile error, but I only see warnings in the output you posted. What is the problem?

Comment: Ok i will keep that in mind for next time. OpenCV build fails in the end even if there are warnings.

Comment: build fails if error(s) exist, warnings should not be a problem. Do you get error?

Comment: edited the question!